# Prestashop's Advanced Top Menu Addon - How to use it correctly

Tags: module, prestashop

I could not find any online docs or even no docs in the extracted folder.
And on prestashop's forum it's like useless to ask questions. *frustrated*

I wanted to make categories appear on top menu, categories go up to 5 levels. But when I tried to configure it, it goes only 2 level and it does not seem to take the default global css.

There is no installation/configuration documents, it's pathetic! And it costs $69!
Anyone have some pointers, would greatly help. thanks!

Comment: if you show the url i can help you.  Which top advanced menu you are using.

Comment: Hi Arifur, thanks for the response.
Sure, the link to this addon is: http://addons.prestashop.com/fr/fonctionnalites-front-office-modules-prestashop/2072-advanced-top-menu-le-meilleur-gestionnaire-de-menu.html

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Top Menu can't manage more than 3 levels :
First level : Tab
Second level : Group of Elements
Third level : Element

But there no limits to category depth. You have to organize your menu content as you want with these 3 levels (by example : a submenu column for each of your category level depth)

About the lack of documentation and your frustration, you have to know that PrestaModule is a major software editor for Prestashop, and they don't leave their customer without any documentation, example and support. So I think you didn't search to reach them or search correctly.

By example :

You could find the documentation here:
www.presta-module.com/docs/en/advancedtopmenu/

A complete demo for a complex menu example with back-office access here:
demos.presta-module.com/advancedtopmenu/en/

And you could contact the PrestaModule team for support here:
http://www.presta-module.com/en/contact-form.php

Hope this helps !

Comment: Stephan I appreciate your response and the pointers you gave.
But one thing, the documentation that comes with this module is so lame! You can clearly see it was done "just for the sake" of making one.

And you want my view on this module? Not the best in terms of quality. I give you an example, when I click submit (B.O) and if there's an error, all my previous entered data are lost. Nice? Tell me about it!

Comment: I'm now trying to contact the support, let's hope they are not as good as the docs!